# .Net Core=I want add personality rules for UserValidator

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, .net-core

For Example;
I have password column in the table. AnyBody while enter system must write password. I want contain password minumum one character such as(/,-,?,+,!). I did such one code;

```
public UserValidator()
{
    RuleFor(p => p.Password).MinimumLength(10);
    RuleFor(p => p.Password).Must(MustBeCharacter);
}
private bool MustBeCharacter(string arg)
{
    return arg.Contains("."+","+"?"+"!"+"*"+"-"+"+");
}
```

I take a problem. system want all of them ("."+","+"?"+"!"+"*"+"-"+"+"). but I want minimum one more. How can I do this rule.
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In your current approach, you are concatenating all special characters into a single string and applying [`Contains()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-6.0) on it. That is the reason, the system expects all special chars should be part of your `arg` string.
- You should define all special characters inside an array or a list, then use [`.Any()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-6.0) to check at least one special car should present in the string `arg`,

  ```
  private bool MustBeCharacter(string arg)
  { 
      var specialChars = ".,?!*-+".ToCharArray();
      return specialChars.Any(x => arg.Contains(x));
  }
  ```

Try online: [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4E2M1D)

Answer (score 0):

System want all of them because you are looking for entire string and not one character.

you need array first

```
private string[] arr = [".",",","?","!","*","-","+"];
private bool MustBeCharacter(string arg)
{  
        return arr.Any(s => args.Contains(s));
    
}
```